# Is session pool of the cloud spanner library for Java FIFO?

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

If it's not FIFO, it will cause an unexpected abort.

Spanner's abort system and the spec of write session is the following;

- If the transactions conflict, the spanner will abort one of them.
- Which transaction should be aborted is basically decided by the start time of the transaction.
- Sessions for write operations start transactions then they're kept in the pool.

If the session pool is not FIFO, there is a possibility that a transaction started by a thread(=A) will be aborted by another transaction started by another thread(=B) even though B takes the session after A takes the session.

Comment: I realized "Which transaction should be aborted is basically decided by the start time of the transaction." is wrong. It's decided by the first operation on the transaction after the BeginTransaction call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java client library, sessions from the session pool are returned in [LIFO order](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/commit/8e35596bdf201d4103ed5c0de7e8926d83af4825) to improve caching and performance on the server side.

Using FIFO vs LIFO in the SessionPool shouldn't have any effect on transaction abort rate. For conflicting transactions, the start time is counted as the first operation on the transaction after the BeginTransaction call. So it shouldn't depend on which session is used.

In addition, as of [v3.0.0](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/releases/tag/v3.0.0), session pool preparing for read/write transactions has been removed, so now the transaction starts when a session is retrieved from the pool when the transaction is run. See details [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/pull/325).